# What would the type definition look like for a function that returns an object that is a subset of an original object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So, I've got a (very, very) large object, and I want to have a function that takes in any object (T) and a list of its keys (K extends keyof T) and returns a new object with only those keys/values that were passed in.  Essentially {[key: K]: string}.

Here is the function in question:

```typescript
export function mapResources(resources, keys: string[]) {
  return keys.reduce((response, key) => ({
      ...response,
      [key]: resources[key]
  }), {});
}
```

I have been trying to write the type definition for this function, but it fails under `TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.`

```typescript
export function mapResources<K extends keyof IResources>(resources: IResources, keys: K[]): {[key: K]: IResources[K]} {
  return keys.reduce((response, key) => ({
      ...response,
      [key as string]: resources[key]
  }), {});
}
```

My goal here is to get that subset object, and have my IDE (and typescript) know what the object looks like based on what was passed in.  I already have a type for resources.  There may be a wholly different approach than how I've started here, I'm just not sure how else to even start typing this.

Comment: Is what you're trying to do something like taking an object {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5} and, by passing it a list of keys like ['b', 'c', 'e'], make a stripped-down copy of the original object like {b: 2, c: 3, e: 5}?

Comment: yes. exactly this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close; you're looking for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which allow you to iterate over keys (as opposed to using an indexer).  That is, don't use this:

```
{[key: K]: IResources[K]}
```

use this instead:

```
{[P in K]: IResources[P]}
```

In fact, this is a useful enough construct that it exists in the [standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.7.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1350) as `Pick<T,K>`:

```
Pick<IResources, K>
```

So your function becomes something like:

```
export function mapResources<K extends keyof IResources>(resources: IResources, keys: K[]): Pick<IResources, K> {
  return keys.reduce((response, key) => ({
      ...response,
      [key as string]: resources[key]
  }), {});
}
```

This will fail to type check in the implementation because I don't think TypeScript understands the spread type on `Pick<IResources, K>`.  If you're sure everything in the implementation is fine, you can use an `any` assertions to help:

```
export function mapResources<K extends keyof IResources>(resources: IResources, keys: K[]): Pick<IResources, K> {
  return keys.reduce((response, key) => ({
      ...(response as any),
      [key]: resources[key]
  }), {});
}
```

You can verify that this behaves as desired (I can't easily do it without knowing what `IResources` is).  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: the `response as any` was the same thing I needed to do as I discovered this on my own. This is the solution, and you posted as the same time as I did!

Comment: I guess I'm learning something new I didn't realize TypeScript could do. So does this mean that a type like this: `type Keys = 'option1' | 'option2'` can be treated both as a type where only those two string are allowed AND as a constant array of those two strings?