# why is extends keys T not a valid index

Tags: typescript

I have this:

```
export function reduceByProp<T, Y extends keyof T>(
  array: T[],
  mapper: (a: T) => Y
): { [key: Y]: T } {
  return array.reduce(
    (previous: T, current: T) => ({ ...previous, [mapper(current)]: current }),
    {}
  );
}
```

but TypeScript is unhappy with `[key: Y]` because an index has the be a `string` or a `number`. But since `Y` is a key of `T` it's by default also a string or a number right?

Comment: No, `keyof` isn't the same as an indexed signature. `keyof` can be a union of literals, which isn't either `string` or `number`. For instance: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=10&pln=7&pc=13#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwBcyAzmFKAOYDc+yARieZSLfQsxdXQL65gAngAcUGdAGkIg5AF5kAa2noYaTHQToQ5ZAA8S4qTPkAiACYmaQA

Comment: Can you show a sample call you're trying to make possible with `reduceByProp`?

Comment: what does [key: Y] mean? is that meant to be an object or an array?

Comment: I'm not saying it's any string I'm saying that since it's used as a key it should be possible to use it as a key again.

Comment: @albertjan - `{[key: Y]: T}` is defining an index signature. In index signatures, the key's type must be `string` or `number`. `keyof` has more nuance than that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not stuggling to get it to work. I'm wondering why `Y extends key T` is not a valid `index` type.

Comment: @albertjan - Well, that's why. Index signatures must use `string` or `number`. `keyof T` is not necessarily `string` or `number`. (BTW: "Look at the code" is ***really*** easy to read as being rude. You probably didn't mean to seem rude there, so just a head's up.)

Comment: when is `keyof T` not a number?

Comment: @Rick I was highlighting the bit of the code that is failing for me. it's a definition of an index type.

Comment: Not sure if it's what's at play here, but this doc says `keyof` produces `string | number | symbol`, so symbol could be messing it up. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining generics with index type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331699/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz - That does seem to cover it. I notice you didn't use your dupehammer, so I've held off doing so as well (I'm not at all sure I should have a TypeScript dupehammer :-) ) to defer to your judgement.

Comment: It's easy for me to tell you to change `{[key: Y]: T}` to `{[K in Y]: T}` but I'm not sure about the rest of your code, since the types seem off to me.  I'd change it to [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYBMQVQIQJ4AKycADgDwAqANIgNKKoAeUqY6AzokaaslHrVR4AfAAoAUIkQBDZMml4AXIgoBtALpVJiALbSSJXstHTlFAJSIAvMLrjLAb21ooIZElny8AOjSZsElJSoiRoAG7wIOw0EG5oYFCWNoiiDojeGaGoEXBRNKp6BryisXKsierKpfFQiAC+5lpBiA51MpxpqgSIMEi06gD8ZvXa5gDc4nXiQA) unless you have a reason why, for example, you want to limit `Y` to be `keyof T` and not just any key at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think this can be closed as a duplicate of that because there are no upvotes there.  I might be able to find another one though; pretty sure I've answered this part before

Comment: I didn’t know about `in` I was just surprised that it didn’t accept `Y` as a valid index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript literal types used as key to indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091528/what-would-the-type-definition-look-like-for-a-function-that-returns-an-object-t?rq=1)

Comment: @jcalz - It can be now. :-) Or of course that second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change your code to look like this:

```
function reduceByProp<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
  array: T[],
  mapper: (a: T) => K
) {
  return array.reduce(
    (previous, current) => ({ ...previous, [mapper(current)]: current }),
    {} as { [P in K]?: T }
  );
}
```

Explaining the differences:

- For your question, you can't do `{[key: K]: T}` or the like, since index signatures are constrained to be *all* strings or all numbers.  Instead you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) of the form `{[P in K]: T}`.
- Unless you want `reduceByProp([{foo: 1}], v => "bar")` to fail, you should make `K extends PropertyKey` and not `K extends keyof T`.  `keyof T` is specifically only the keys inside the objects in your array, while `PropertyKey` is any key you want.
- Don't annotate `previous` and `current`, or if you do annotate them, don't annotate them as `T`.  `current` is definitely `T`, but `previous` is an accumulator and is not `T` but the return type of `reduceByProp()` which is something whose keys are returned by `mapper()` and whose value types are `T`.
- Give the initial reduce object `{}` an explicit type, or otherwise specify what `reduce()` is expected to produce.  The value `{}` will be inferred as type `{}` otherwise, which will fail to type check.  So I've given it `{} as ...`.
- I've made the return type `{[P in K]?: T}` in which the properties are optional (`?`) instead of required as in `{[P in K]: T}`.  The reason is that you might want to make a call like this:

  ```
  reduceByProp([{ foo: 1 }, { foo: 3 }, { foo: 5 }], v => v.foo % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd");
  ```

  The return type of that in my version is `{even?: {foo: number}, odd?: {foo: number}}`.  It's good that those are optional because it turns out that the output has no `even` key at all.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYBMQVQIQJ4AKycADgDwAqANIgNKKoAeUqY6AzokaaslHrVR4AfAAoAUIkQBDZMml4AXIgoBtALpVJiALbSSJXstHTlFAJSIAvMLrjLAb0Ta0UEMiSz5eAHRpM2BJSUqIkaABu8CDsNBDuaGBQljaIok4+GWGokXDRNKp6BryicXKsSerKpQlQiAC+5lrBiA51MpxOqgSIMEi06gD8ZvXa5gDc4nXi4v5YuITEJKKqTsBwcMoAjPWaiOHWtgBEAEayh+bTs9j43EsriGsbiNt1NKvrygDM9W8PH4gAVh2NH2KXCPkeiAApIgAEzWKxWRAABkQA0Qh2yrEOiGUhzg6HQ5wm0yAA)